# Using LINQ to filter out lines in textfile C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble using LINQ with 2 predicates. Basically, I need to remove a line from a text file which matches my predicates below. But it is not working and ONLY the lines for a particular `Environment.MachineName` are being removed.

**EDIT: Added input data for rLogonTime**

```
private static string rLogonTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString();

var oldLines = File.ReadAllLines(rLogonPath);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(x => !x.Contains(Environment.MachineName) && !x.Contains(rLogonTime)); //<--
File.WriteAllLines(rLogonPath, newLines);
```

Is it possible to do this? Or is there another way?

Cheers.

**EDIT: Once again, I apologise for not being clear.**

`rLogonTime` is a static string, my text file DOES contain the same value as it does in DEBUG mode in my app. IF I try

```
var newLines = oldLines.Where(x => !x.Contains(rLogonTime));
```

on its own, it works. Same for `Environment.MachineName`

But they DO NOT work together.

Also, a couple of lines from the text file as requested.

```
u####,######!,####.vshost.exe,31/10/2014,11:58:11 AM,PC-67027
u####,######!,####.vshost.exe,31/10/2014,12:15:02 PM,PC-65027
```

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Why would it remove no lines?  The logic says that it should keep all lines that don't contain one thing and don't contain another thing.  It removes all lines containing either thing.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Appologies, I edited my question above, it removes ONLY lines for a particular machine name, but doesn't check for `rLogonTime`.

Comment: @TonyMontana it checks for rLogonTime for sure. It just doesn't match any. Possibly because of datetime format differences.

Comment: So instead of `&&` its applying `||` ? Is there a way to group the predicate then? `(bool)(!x.Contains(Environment.MachineName) && !x.Contains(rLogonTime))` ?

Comment: @TonyMontana No, the code (that is shown) is fine.  Your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and `rLogonTime`?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk `private static string rLogonTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString();`

Comment: And input data? I assume it doesn't contain `DateTime` now...

Comment: Also, I should add that if I only use `Environment.MachineName` or `rLogonTime` it works, but NOT when I look for both to be false.

Comment: it will be more clear if you share your test data or unit test itself

Comment: @GrantWinney rLogonTime is a static string which gets written to the file when the application is run.

Comment: @Tony, can you observe you rLogonPath file whether it contains `DateTime.Now`? :D

Comment: Edited question once again. To be clear that rLogonTime and MachineName are always the same.

Comment: I added a couple of lines from the text file in the initial question above. cheers.

Comment: Magic happens here! :D

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You need to remove lines which contain machine name and some 'time', right? E.g.: time = `10:10:10`. Machine name = `ABC`. Lines are: `[1]ABC 10:10:10 [2]ABC 11:11:11 [3]XYZ 10:10:10` Which lines should be removed?

Comment: Are you just wanting this: `var newLines = oldLines.Where(x => !(x.Contains(Environment.MachineName) && x.Contains(rLogonTime)));`?

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk line [1] would need to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is almost correct. You want to exclude all lines that contain `Environment.MachineName` and `rLogonTime`, so the lines you want to exclude are ones that:

```
contains MachineName AND contains LogonTime
```

So wrap that all in a NOT:

```
var newLines = oldLines.Where(x => !(x.Contains(Environment.MachineName) && x.Contains(rLogonTime)))
```